# Get Rows from table where column one has same value and column 2 has a different value

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

[image: Table1]

I need to find all the rows where col2 has same value but col3 has a different value .From the table above , It should return Pk1,Pk3 and Pk4. I tried the following a self join but i see duplicate records .

```
 SELECT  T1.COL1,T1.COL2,T1.COl3
    FROM Tab T1, Tab T2
        WHERE T1.Col2=T2.Col1 
        AND T1.Col3 <> T2.Col3
```

;

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col3 <> t.col3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Analytic functions are better for this kind of job - they avoid all joins. For example:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from   (
         select t.*, 
                case when min(col3) over (partition by col2) != 
                          max(col3) over (partition by col2) then 0 end as flag
         from   tab t
       )
where  flag = 0;
```

It is not entirely clear how you want to handle `null` in `col3` - does that count as a "different" value? What if you have `null` more than once (for the same value in `col2`)? Also - what if `col2` can be `null`?

Comment: Ignore rows where the values in  col2 , col3  are null or 0

Comment: @user68883 - that's easy: in the **subquery** add a `where` clause, for example `where col2 != 0 and col3 != 0`. This will also guarantee, automatically, that they are not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM
(SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3, COUNT(DISTINCT COL3) OVER (PARTITION BY COL2) CNT
FROM TEST)
WHERE CNT > 1
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25f150dbb25b2c1ddded52cb5a2a2189)

Cheers!!